# creating a horizontal line over a textview in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i am making a math tutor for school kids... In it's Subtraction lesson, I want to make a horizontal line over a textview while taking a borrow from a number.
Look at the image below. The line created on Textview.How it can be done programaticaly.. [image: just like this].

Comment: try This 
 textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

Comment: @AndroidGeeks can i increase it's width????

Comment: Check my edited answer to change height of strike

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

To change hight of textView strike create drawable file **strike.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

in your xml set textview background

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:background="@drawable/strike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```